# amcl on quadrotor

Tags: navigation, uav, hokuyo, amcl, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey im trying to use AMCL on an asctec pelican, im using odometry from the imu which is not very good. i am able to make a map from hector mapping without odometry, but amcl dosent work , my tf is map -> odom -> base_link -> base_laser , im using a hokuyo laser range finder
this is the error im getting
TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame /base_link at time 0 according to authority /odometry_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at
plus
Message from [/hokuyo_node] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [laser_link]. Resolved locally to [/laser_link].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
can someone please tell me what im missing ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12802/amcl-on-quadrotor/) by [vivek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1350/vivek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-01-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [polde](https://answers.ros.org/users/32229/polde/) on 2017-12-28**:
Hi ! Do you have any code to share about this project?
I'm trying to develop something similar..
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If I've understood things correctly the tf name 'base_laser' and the frame ID in the laser nodes scan messages, 'laser_link', should be identical. Otherwise AMCL won't know what position the scan was recorded from. Though, if that was the problem I think you should have seen an error message... But better fix it.

The message about the frame ID not being qualified can be ignored. It just means that if you have several robots, the system won't be able to tell apart their scans because the frame ID doesn't have a "//" prefix.

About the TD_OLD_DATA, are you playing back data using rosbag? Have you run "rosparam set use_sim_time true" before starting any nodes? Do you use the --clock option when running "rosbag play"? Is the warning message repeated, or only displayed at the beginning?

---

Originally posted by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) with karma: 317 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kedarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5211/kedarm/) on 2013-10-03**:
Just in case you're interested in solving the non-fully qualified frame ID warning....take a look at this: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5511